# Arithmetic expression in prolog solving

Tags: prolog

given an expression:
`(x*0+6)*(x-x+3+y*y)` and value of y:2 the Predicate  should give only one

solution `(x*0+6)*(x-x+3+4).`

when `6*(3+x*x) and x:2` is given then it should give the output 42 .
I have been coding for hours and i could manage to get only the second part of it .my code is posted below .can some one help me with solution .

```
partial_eval(Expr0, Var,Val, Expr) :-
   evaluate(Expr0,[Var:Val],Expr).

evaluate(Exp, LstVars, Val) :-
   analyse(LstVars, Exp, NewExp),
   Val is NewExp.

analyse(LstVars, Term,R) :-
   functor(Term, Term, 0), !,
   (   member(Term : V, LstVars)
   ->  R = V
   ;   R = Term ).
analyse(LstVars, Term, V) :-
   functor(Term, Name, _),
   Term =.. [Name | Lst],
   maplist(analyse(LstVars), Lst, LstV),
   V =.. [Name|LstV].
```

Comment: How are you calling your code? What are you expecting versus what you are seeing? I would probably prefer using `compound/1` and `atomic/1` to distinguish my cases instead of functor/3. I think you're expecting `x+1+y+2 =.. V` to unify `V = [+, x, 1, y, 2]`, but unfortunately it instead yields `V = [+, x+1+y, 2]`; is this part of the problem? Perhaps in the second rule for `analyse/3` you need to recursively call `analyse/3`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for your question?

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be broken down into two: One is substituting in values for variables. The other is recursively evaluating arithmetic subexpressions. Prolog is nondeterministic but both of these operations are deterministic, so that's something to keep in mind while implementing them.

You seem to have a good generic recursion structure (using =..) for the substitution part. For the arithmetic evaluation part you may find it easier to use + and * terms in the recursion. Hope that helps you get started, ask if you get stuck and need more advice.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some code as to how to proceed with your solution? I have an almost similar question to solve.

Comment: @Katherine it would be best to ask this as a new question.